# Herokuにおけるhttp://127.0.0.1:8080とは？

Tags: python, heroku

Python-FitbitというFitbit APIをPythonから利用するモジュールで、Heroku上のプログラムからOAuth2認証をして、アクセストークン・リフレッシュトークンを取得したい。

Python-Fitbit
https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit

手順はこのサイトを参考にしました。
http://blog.mr-but-dr.xyz/programming/fitbit-python-heartrate-howto/

ローカルでhttp://127.0.0.1:8080をコールバックURLに指定しプログラムを実行すると、ブラウザが開き認証に成功するのですが、Heroku上でhttps://appname.herokuapp.com:443/をコールバックURLに指定し実行すると、認証に失敗します。

Herokuにおけるhttp://127.0.0.1:8080が何にあたるのかを教えてください。
ポート番号を8080や5000に変えてみましたが、同じエラーが発生しました。

gather_keys_oauth2.py

```
import cherrypy
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host':'appname.herokuapp.com','server.socket_port':443})

def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret,
             redirect_uri='https://appname.herokuapp.com:443'):
```

エラーメッセージ

```
    raise socket.error(msg)
OSError: No socket could be created -- (('IPアドレス', 443): [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address)
```

エラーメッセージ2

```
[17/Apr/2017:14:01:15] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <bound method Server.start of <cherrypy._cpserver.Server object at 0x7f33e57b12e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 215, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 168, in start
    super(Server, self).start()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 177, in start
    portend.free(*self.bind_addr, timeout=Timeouts.free)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/portend.py", line 143, in free
    raise Timeout("Port {port} not free on {host}.".format(**locals()))
portend.Timeout: Port 443 not free on appname.herokuapp.com.

[17/Apr/2017:14:01:15] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start listener:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 253, in start
    self.publish('start')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 233, in publish
    raise exc
cherrypy.process.wspbus.ChannelFailures: Timeout('Port 443 not free on appname.herokuapp.com.',)
```

Comment: この編集だと既存の回答とまったく整合しなくなってしまいましたね。
私のコメントが不適切でした。新しい投稿にするようお願いするべきでしたね。
申し訳ないです。
もし今からでも新しい投稿に出来るようでしたら、お願いします。
あと、コンソールの文字列はコピー出来ますので、スクリーンショットでは無く、文字列として貼り付けるようにして下さい。（新しく投稿される場合は、この投稿は「ロールバック」出来ますので、心配は無用です)

Comment: Fitbitの事はまったく分かりませんが、想像するに、`redirect_uri` も Heroku の URL を指定するべきなのだと思います。
`{port}.format(**vars())`というのは何でしょうね……始めのソースには無かったようですが、こういう物なのでしょうか。

Comment: ロールバックしました。あらためて投稿しなおします。アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「認証に失敗します」との事ですが、そもそもサーバの起動に失敗している気がします。

Heroku では使用するポート番号を[環境変数 `$PORT` から取得します](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#web-dynos)。
どうも デフォルトが`5000`のようで、`int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))` のようにしてポートを決定するのが定石のようですね。

Listen するインターフェースをとりあえず、`0.0.0.0`（全て）にするなら、設定は下記のようになるかと思います。

```
cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000')),
})
```

まずはサーバの起動を成功させましょう。

Comment: その場合、dev.fitbit.comに登録するURはhttps://0.0.0.0になるのでしょうか(herokuのポートは指定しなくていい？)

以下のコードで実行してみましたが、

cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000')),
})
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))

    def __init__(self, client_id, client_secret,
                 redirect_uri='https://0.0.0.0:{port}.format(**vars())'):

「[17/Apr/2017:15:33:43] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:41435
[17/Apr/2017:15:33:43] ENGINE Bus STARTED」

とコンソールにメッセージが表示されたまま、処理が先に進みません。
(ローカルでhttp://127.0.0.1:8080の設定で実行した場合は、次の処理に進みました)

Comment: @sashihara  私がお答え出来るのはサーバの起動方法までです。
エラーメッセージが無くなり、サーバの起動が出来たならば以降はお役に立てません。
このコメント欄は他の方は見ていないですから、投稿を編集して情報を追加するか、新しい質問を投稿なさるのがよいです。
（常識的に考えると、「dev.fitbit.comに登録する」のは Heroku の URL だろうとは思います）

Answer (score 0):

リダイレクト先はOAuthのプロバイダにあらかじめ登録したCallback URLです。

> 手順はこのサイトを参考にしました。

そのサイトは、アプリをローカル環境で動かすことを前提にしているようです。
このため、以下のようにかかれています。

> ・Callback URL => http://127.0.0.1:8080/ ※ここも重要です

dev.fitbit.com に上記のように登録すると、OAuth認証後のリダイレクト先は当然 127.0.0.1:8080 になります。
herokuで動作刺せているのであれば、herokuのURL&portをdev.fitbit.comに登録する必要があると思います。

Comment: 説明が足りませんでした。dev.fitbit.comにherokuapp.com:PORT番号を登録した上での、エラーです。